# How do I replace comma with hyphen within the double quotes in json

Tags: json, power-automate

I am processing a CSV file in powerautomate. Here is one record.

```
server2,usa,"rebooted,by citrix",25,good
```

Because "rebooted,by citrix" is data from a single field, when I am splitting with comma, the array manipulation gets mismatch.
I want to replace the comma within double quotes with hyphen. The expected output should be like `server2,usa,"rebooted-by citrix",25,good`

Answer (score 0):

PrasadAthalye has a nice solution approach for this.

You could first split on the " character instead. Per item you could replace the , character and append the results to a new array. After that you should be able to apply your normal split.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Setting-up-specific-expression-to-remove-comma-inside-strings/m-p/646040/highlight/true#M86288